# How do I find the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac 1 {z(1-z^2)}$ and $g(z)=\frac 1 {z^2(1-z^2)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I find the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac 1 {z(1-z^2)}$ and $g(z)=\frac 1 {z^2(1-z^2)}$ ?

I've tried computing the derivative by trial and error, but I don't get anything nice.

Is there a clever way ?

Comment: Partial fractions perhaps?

Comment: Start with a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: around which point ? 0, 1 or -1 ?

Comment: around the point 0

Answer (score 0):

For $f$ around $z=0$ :

$$f(z)=...=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{1-z}}_{=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{1+z}}_{=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^k}=...$$

For $g$ around $z=0$ :

$$g(z)=...=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+z}=...$$

Comment: why does the second series start with $k=1$ ?

Comment: It's my error. I corrected it :-)